# Laravel 4 Eloquent - where timestamp is over 3 years old

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a field called RegistrationDate which I need to check for time since.

I need a where claus that will do:

```
if (time() - strtotime($car->RegistrationDate) > 3*365.25*24*60*60)
    over 3 years old
}
```

So:

```
$cars::where('RegistrationDate', '>', '3 years old')->get();
```

but don't know how to do that, my dates are saved as timestamps: 2009-07-17 00:00:00.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Carbon Library. I think it is loaded by the laravel framework already. But if not you can load via composer. https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

`$cars::where('RegistrationDate', '>', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subYears(3))->get();` Assuming `$cars` is an eloquent object for your `Car` model;

Also, unrelated to question... but your table naming conventions are a bit weird.

`$cars = Car::where('registration_date', '>', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subYears(3))->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTimeInterval](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/php-dateinterval-class/) class:

```
$currentDate = new DateTime(); // get current date time
$currentDate->sub(new DateInterval('P3Y')); // substract 3 years from current date
```

After that you can use `$currentDate` in your code like:

```
$cars::where('RegistrationDate', '>', $currentDate)->get();
```

You can also convert `$currentDate` to sql datetime string you needed with:

```
$currentDateStr = $currentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```